# How to include a library which I installed with Homebrew

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, libraries

I have installed the boost library with homebrew and if I write:

```
include_directories(/opt/homebrew/Cellar)
link_directories(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/)
add_executable(Project main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Project boost)
```

And then include it in my script:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;
```

It doesn't find it, when I write:

```
#include <boost/1.76.0/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;
```

It does find it but I get following error:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:12:10: fatal error: 'boost/multiprecision/number.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>
The number.hpp file can't include the boost library.
```

Can anyone make sense out of this and can help me?

Comment: It's preferrable to use `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS multiprecision) ... 
target_link_libraries(Project PRIVATE Boost::multiprecision)` (not 100% sure if the component is submodule and how you'd include boost as header only lib in cmake. You may need to specify the install dir via `Boost_ROOT` or `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a Boost header-only library, such as `multiprecision` with cmake, usually all you need to do is:

```
find_package(Boost)
link_libraries(Boost::headers)
```

---

In case Boost was not installed correctly, you might still add it with:

```
include_directories(/opt/homebrew/include)
```

or:

```
include_directories(/opt/homebrew/Celler/boost/1.76.0/include)
```